# Incrementing register in Assembler x86 doesn't go above value of 1

Tags: assembly, x86, increment, x86-16, cpu-registers

I'm pretty new to Assembler, I just need to complete my school task, but I have one little problem. The program should read two-digit numbers on input and count all the numbers that are greater than the first one. The problem is that register EDX (used for counting greater numbers) increments up to 1, but not above it. Can you suggest something not too complicated?

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
segment .data
char_prompt    db  "Insert numbers: ",0
comma           db  ", ",0
out_msg1       db  "Count of numbers greater than the first number(",0
out_msg2       db  "): ",0

segment .text
global _asm_main
_asm_main:
enter 0,0
pusha

mov     EAX, char_prompt
call    print_string

first_number:
call    read_char
cmp     EAX, 32
je      first_number
cmp     EAX, 10
je      after_input
cmp     EAX, 13
je      after_input
sub     EAX, 48     ; turn ASCII code into a digit
mov     EBX, 10
mul     EBX         ; multiply decimal point by 10
mov     EBX, EAX
call    read_char
sub     EAX, 48     ; turn ASCII code into a digit
add     EAX, EBX    ; add decimals and units together
mov     ECX, EAX
call    print_int
mov     EAX, comma
call    print_string
jmp     main_loop


main_loop:
call    read_char
cmp     EAX, 32
je      main_loop
cmp     EAX, 10
je      after_input
cmp     EAX, 13
je      after_input
sub     EAX, 48     ; turn ASCII code into a digit
mov     EBX, 10
mul     EBX         ; multiply decimal point by 10
mov     EBX, EAX
call    read_char
sub     EAX, 48     ; turn ASCII code into a digit
add     EAX, EBX    ; add decimals and units together
mov     EBX, EAX
call    print_int
mov     EAX, comma
call    print_string
mov     EAX, EBX
cmp     EAX, ECX    ; compare current number to first number
ja      increase
jmp     main_loop

increase:
inc     EDX         ; increase count of greater numbers <-- PROBLEM HERE
jmp     main_loop

after_input:
mov     EAX, out_msg1
call    print_string
mov     EAX, ECX
call    print_int
mov     EAX, out_msg2
call    print_string
mov     EAX, EDX
call    print_int
jmp     finish

finish:
popa                 ; terminate program
mov EAX, 0
mov EBX, 0
mov ECX, 0
mov EDX, 0
leave
ret
```

The format of output is still pretty raw, I'm going to correct it once I solve that main issue.

I also tried

```
add EDX, 1
```

instead of

```
inc EDX
```

but it was the same result.

I would be really grateful if someone helped me.

Comment: Step through in a debugger line by line. You will see something happen to the edx register at the mul instruction.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that both INC and ADD work pretty well :) It rather looks like somewhere in you code, (usually one of your subfunctions) EDX is used. Try a `push edx` right at the beginning of your loop, and `pop edx` before you increase it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hidden parameters**
The problem is that some instructions in the x86 instruction set take hidden parameters.

**`mul` sucks**
In your case it's the `MUL` instruction.

`mul ebx` is a misnomer. It is really:

```
mul edx:eax, eax, ebx
    ^^^^^^^  ^^^  ^^^
      |||     |    +-------- Source 1
      |||     +------------- Source 2
      +++------------------- Destination
```

That is `mul ebx` translates to: `EDX:EAX = EAX * EBX`.

So instead of 1 operand `mul` takes 3.

You can see this at:  http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MUL.html

The reason for this is that a multiply of two 32 bit operands can produce a 64-bit number. In order to facilitate this the processor stores the result in two registers. The lower 32 bits go into `EAX` and the higher 32 bits go into `EDX`. 
In your case you are multiplying small numbers so `EDX` always ends up with zero, which neatly explains why EDX will never get above one.
-You keep on resetting it back to zero-.

The solution is to use another register for the counter, e.g. `EDI`. 
But be careful, because EDI is also used as a hidden parameter in the [string instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-5477/eoizn/index.html).
If you're using those, then you'll need to either `push edx` before and `pop edx` after the `mul` instruction or use `imul`.

**`imul` rules**
This instruction allows you to specify explicit operands.

`imul eax,ebx`

This instruction will translate to the following pseudo code: `eax = eax * ebx`.
`imul` performs a s̲i̲gn̲e̲d̲ m̲u̲l̲t̲i̲pl̲y(!), which is probably fine for your use case, but something to be aware of. It will also throw away overflow bits, but you don't need to worry about that in your code.

**Finally**
If you're multiplying times a constant you can just do:

```
imul ebx,eax,10
```

Condensing 3 instructions into 1, and avoiding clobbering `edx`.

**About calling conventions**
If any of those routines that you call modify any registers you'll also run into trouble. I'm assuming that your routines use `pusha/popa` throughout, but if any registers are clobbered by subroutines you'll need to compensate for that in your code.

If you call library functions, these will adhere to a [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) which specify which registers are preserved by the called routine and which registers can be altered.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used imul for simplicity and it works flawlessly. I had no idea that EDX is used in multiplication, although it makes sense. You just saved me few days of debugging!

Comment: @MartinRyuStraka, It pays to read the documentation for the instructions. There are quite a few gotchas.

Comment: Why are you emphasizing 2-operand `imul`'s signedness? It only matters for the flags, and they're rarely used..